# making an object accessible to child instances only

Tags: c#, static

i have the following class

```
public class Manager
{
   public SharedObject sharedobj {get;set;}
   public SomeObject someobj {get;set;}
   public AnotherObject anotherobj {get;set;}
   //...
}
```

i want `sharedobj` to be only accessible from any instance that is in the `Manager` class instance

making it static is not an option since i will have multiple instances of the Manager class, so the only thing in my mind is sending the sharedobj to the constructors of each object that will use it, i was wondering if there is a better way to achive such thing without having to reference the `sharedobj` in each instance that will need to use it.

another way i thought of is using the protected keyword and make the other classes inherit the manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[protected (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The protected keyword is a member access modifier. A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class instances. For a comparison of protected with the other access modifiers, see Accessibility Levels.

This is assuming you want each to have his own shared object that you can access if you have the manager.

---

On a side note, you could also use [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (a.k.a DI) to do it. Here's the easiest, shortest explanation of DI I've seen so far: http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/Dependency-Injection-Demystified.html .

It's a bit more advanced approach with it's own positives and negatives like everything else, but at least read the short link I've mentioned so you'll have an idea of what it is.

Comment: each manager have his own value of the SharedObject, and the child instances above will have to use the SharedObject that is inatilized in the Manager instance

Comment: In that case, change the `public` to `protected` and only the class and the childrens will be able to access it.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to pass it to each object, just as you wrote. Either in the constructor or simply make a setter in `SomeObject` and `AnotherObject`, and use that. I would go with what you wrote, and pass it through the constructors.

On a sidenote, if nothing else but the objects within Manager should use SharedObject, then it probably should be private instead of public in the Manager class.

Comment: but the problem is i have about 19 instances in the manager and i find it disturbing to have to pass it to each constructor

Comment: Does all the classes which use SharedObject use it in the same way? It sounds like you should have a super class for them. But I don't think you will get around passing the reference. Eventually you could make a list of the objects, loop through it and set the reference (if they had the same base class). But I think constructors would be the way to go, if the objects "needs" the sharedObject - because the constructor forces you to set it.

Comment: yes they share the same base class and i am sending the reference to each constructor now, but why not just use the protected keyword?

Comment: Well I saw that you had made the "sharedobj" property public in your snippet. If nothing outside Manager uses SharedObject then it probably should be private. Protected would make it available to classes which are derived from Manager. I don't know if you have any classes which are sub classes of Manager. But if you do and they need access to the property, then it should be protected.